# How to not delete pointer's value without using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, destructor, shared-ptr

I am implementing a Tree, every Node has Node** inside it for the sons:

```
class Node {
    string word;
    Node* father;
    Node** sons; 
    int sonsNum;
    ....
}
```

for inserting new son I coudnt find a way instead of making new[] array of Node* and deleting the old one (I cant use list, I am restrected...). but when deleting the old Node** using delete[], even I have saved the pointers inside to another tmp array, its values will be gone! (even Node destrucor is empty! why?). so if I use shared_ptr I think it will solve it, is there a way to do that without shared_ptr?

```
void insertSon(Node* sn) {
    sn->father=this;
    Node** tmpSons = sons;  //should be shared_ptr? but I dont want that
    if(sons)
        //delete[](sons);   // after this line, tmpSons has garbage!
    sons = new Node*[sonsNum+1];
    for(int i=0 ; i<sonsNum ; i++) {
        sons[i]=tmpSons[i];
    }
    sons[sonsNum]=sn;
    sonsNum++;
}
```

edit:
sorry forgot to said I want the real values inside the nodes so I cant copy. ( the string in this code is just for the example... its another object in real..)

edit:
solution:

```
void insertSon(Node* sn) {
    sn->father=this;
    Node** tmpSons = new Node*[sonsNum];    
    for(int i=0 ; i<sonsNum ; i++) {
        tmpSons[i]=sons[i];
    }
    if(sons)
        delete[](sons);
    sons = new Node*[sonsNum+1];
    for(int i=0 ; i<sonsNum ; i++) {
        sons[i]=tmpSons[i];
    }
    sons[sonsNum]=sn;
    sonsNum++;
    delete[](tmpSons);
}
```

Comment: You just copy the value of a pointer and delete what it points at. Pointers aren't reference counted.

Comment: sorry forgot to said I want the real values inside the nodes

Comment: Why don't you just assign the pointer and not delete the original one?

Comment: because I need a bigger one. so I need new[old_size +1]. and then must delete the old one!

Comment: you could put the nodes in a `vector<Node*>`

Comment: I cant use any database...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Node** tmpSons = sons;  //should be shared_ptr? but I dont want that
if(sons)
    //delete[](sons);   // after this line, tmpSons has garbage!
```

Yes, that's normal -- the contents of `tmpSons` will be invalidated since it's just pointing to the same memory as `sons`, and you're freeing its contents with `operator delete[]`.

There's no need to involve reference counting to solve this kind of problem. Simply allocate a new array (without touching `sons`), copy the contents of `sons` to the new, bigger array, and *then* free the memory of `sons` and make `sons` point to the new block. The key is to not free the contents of `sons` until you're finished copying it to your new array. It's like you don't want to throw away that CD you're copying until *after* you copy it (your original version was sort of throwing it away before the copy was even made). Something like this:

```
void insertSon(Node* sn) {
    sn->father = this;

    // Create a new array and copy the old data.
    Node** new_sons = new Node*[sonsNum+1];
    for(int i=0; i<sonsNum; i++)
        new_sons[i] = sons[i];
    new_sons[sonsNum++] = sn;

    // Delete old data.
    delete[] sons;

    // Point to the new data.
    sons = new_sons;
}
```

That should hold you up until you start worrying about things like exception-safety, at which point you probably do want to avoid relying too much on these manual memory management techniques and use more RAII-conforming objects.

**Visual Breakdown**

Here's a visual breakdown. First we start with the `sons` pointer which points go a memory block containing some "sons" of a "father" (very patriarchal naming conventions for a nodal system, btw).

[image]

---

Then we allocate a new, slightly bigger memory block which will be pointed to by `new_sons`:

```
Node** new_sons = new Node*[sonsNum+1];
```

[image]

---

Next we copy the former son entries into the new array.

```
for(int i=0; i<sonsNum; i++)
    new_sons[i] = sons[i];
```

[image]

---

... and add our new entry.

```
new_sons[sonsNum++] = sn;
```

[image]

---

Now that we have a copy, we can throw away the old data.

```
// Delete old data.
delete[] sons;
```

[image]

---

... last but not least, we can make `sons` point to the new data. `new_sons` will then go out of scope and the pointer will be destroyed as well (not the stuff it's pointing to, just the pointer), and we'll end up getting what we want (`sons` now pointing to a new array, one entry bigger, with both the old entries and the new entry we added).

```
// Point to the new data.
sons = new_sons;
```

[image]

... and you're done.

Comment: We don't want to `delete[] new_sons` in this function since it's going to end up being pointed to by `sons` -- basically it's like we made a copy of the CD, now we can throw the old one and just use the new one, but you don't want to throw away the new one too, since we're going to end up using the new (slightly bigger) one through `sons` which will now point to the new one.

Comment: I was feeling bored so I gave a visual breakdown of what the code is doing at the pointer level. I think that might help you understand the separation between the pointers and the memory contents they point to a little better.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
Node** tmpSons = sons;
```

it doesn't copy the actual memory itself only the pointer, which means that you have two pointers both pointing to the same memory.

If you do `delete[]` on one of the pointers, then the other pointer will become a *stray* pointer, as it now points to unallocated memory. Dereferencing any of the pointers will lead to *undefined behavior*

Comment: @Atheel You can't avoid it using a `std::shared_ptr` only for `tmpSons`, you need to use it for `sons` too and everywhere you use this pointer. The smart pointers only wraps the *pointer* and not the memory it points to. And besides, you should really look at the smart pointers more from a resource ownership point of view, can a resource have multiple simultaneous owners then use `std::shared_ptr`, or can the resource only have one owner at a time then use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: acctually yes I can!! your answer just gave me the idea! thanks. see my edit for solution

Answer (score 2):

> but when deleting the old Node** using delete[], even I have saved the pointers inside to another tmp array, its values will be gone! (even Node destrucor is empty! why?)

But you haven't saved the pointers inside to another array. You do that after deleting the `Node**`. After you've deleted something, accessing it's content will have undefined behaviour.

> is there a way to do that without shared_ptr?

Sure, delete `tmpSons` **after** you've copied it's content.

> I cant use list, I am restrected...

I recommend using a vector.